# How to get Variants field for Page Content

Tags: sxa

I'm extending the SXA Accordion component to add a header to the accordion.  Ok, derive a template from Accordion template, add the Page Component to the presentation details for the standard values, create a new controller, model, repository and view, all based on the Accordion component.

```
        @if (Model.Rendering.DataSourceItem != null)
        {
            if (Model.Title == null)
            {
                using (Html.Sxa().BeginEditFrame(Html.Sitecore().CurrentRendering.DataSource, "Header Empty", Model.IsControlEditable))
                {
                    <div class="accordion-header">
                    [Heading is empty]
                    </div>
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (Html.Sxa().BeginEditFrame(Model.Title.ID, "Header", Model.IsControlEditable))
                {
                    var titleKey = string.Format("{0}-{1}", titleBaseKey, Model.Id);
                    <div class="accordion-header">
                        @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder(titleKey)
                    </div>
                }
            }
        }
```

In the new template, I added a Title field (rich text).  The Title field in the model is just the rendering DataSourceItem.  How do I get the Title field of the new template to show up as a variant in the rendering parameters for the Page Content?  Remember the new template has the Accordion as the base template.

Comment: I don't get the question.. why do you need "Page Content" if your title field is in the datasource template?

Comment: I a using the Page Content to allow a the rich text editor to be used to edit content.  Is there some other way I should be doing this?

Comment: I can change this to use the rich text for the presentation details, but it still won't let me choose the field name to use for the variant.

Answer (score 1):

I found that adding the template to the `experienceAccelerator/getVariants/allowedTemplates` in a **configuration** file seemed to make this work.